# Android Studio: Missing Android Support Repository

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I have installed a fresh version (4.0.1) of AndroidStudio and am now trying to get a project to build and run which I rescued from an older installation. When I connect my phone and try to run one of the application modules, I am getting the error:

"Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26"

I have read about the Android Support Repository in the SDK manager, but it seems to be missing in my installation:

[image]

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.kohaerenzstiftung.rc"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':kohaerenzstiftung')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26'
}
```

I added

```
compile "com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1"
```

at the very end.

Now I am getting the error

[image]

What do I have to do?

Comment: You have to add support library dependency in `build.gradle` file

Comment: Please edit your post and include your `build.gradle` file otherwise you should paste this in it `compile "com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1"`